# How to install the blue stripes animated wallpaper in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

How can I install the default Gnome-Shell 3.4 animated background (or 'wallpaper') in Ubuntu 12.10?

The background is dynamic, becoming brighter and more radiant during the day, and dark and shadowy in the evening.

**Morning, Daytime and Night**
[image]

I tried to install the package "gnome-backgrounds" but there are only the static backgrounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background is part of the default *Adwaita* GNOME theme. You have to install the *gnome-themes-standard* package.

In Ubuntu 20.04-22.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-themes-standard
```

Comment: Thanks!

Unfortunately,in the latest version of gnome this theme is much [lighter and brighter](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-themes-standard/plain/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/morning.jpg). However I created [an archive](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/202594/adwaita-3.4-background.tar.gz) containing the theme of version 3.4.

Comment: the archive mentioned by @RobertoLeinardi seems down (404). IS there any other source available to get this good wallpaper for i.e. 16.04